# Trying to enter a date in one cell so it populates 2 different cells in an Access table

Tags: date, ms-access

I want to add date to a cell in a table in Access so that based on that date entry it will populate 25 days in advance in different cell and 30 days in advance in another cell.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use a query as you never should store calculated values in a table:

```
Select 
    [DateEntered],
    DateAdd("d", 25, [DateEntered]) As Date25,
    DateAdd("d", 30, [DateEntered]) As Date30
From
    YourTable
```

Comment: It worked!!  OMG.  I can't thank you enough.  I am building a database for work and I haven't done coding since 1998...so I feel clueless!  Thanks again!!  You are the best!!

Comment: How do I do that...sorry I am new...I will investigate.  :)  Thanks again.  I figured it out I think...check mark.  :)